# Why does async prevent the twitter callback from firing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm in the process of converting some basic node scripts into Lambda functions. One of the scripts uses the twitter SDK to fetch some tweets. This is essentially the example of how to call the API with the basic AWS Lambda boiler plate. If you run this, the callback wont fire and it will basically skip over the twitter.get function. However if you remove the async from the exports.handler function it fires how one would expect.

I thought I understood async await, but why does it prevent callbacks from being fired? Perhaps the twitter SDK senses when its an async function and returns a promise?

```
const Twitter = require('twitter');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log("The function started") // this line gets logged

const twitter = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.consumer_key,
  consumer_secret: process.env.consumer_secret,
  access_token_key: process.env.access_token_key,
  access_token_secret: process.env.access_token_secret
});

  const params = {
    screen_name: 'xxxx',
    count: 10,
    tweet_mode: 'extended'
  };
  const twitterEndpoint = 'statuses/user_timeline.json';


twitter.get(twitterEndpoint, params,  function(error, tweets, response) { //this doesn't...
    console.log("TWEETS", tweets, "ERROR", error, "RESPONSE", response) // this line does not log out
    if (!error) {
      console.log(tweets)
    }else{
      console.log(error, "There was an error calling twitter!")
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you share how you call the function in the code where you import it?

Comment: Im firing from the AWS Lambda console. When I run the function  `console.log("The function started")` is logged out so I know the code is being ran.

Comment: This is not about the twitter SDK at all then, but about the AWS lambda handler. Guess is if the handler function is async, AWS Lambda excepts a promise. Posting an answer on how to promisify your `twitter.get()` to use async function with AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow-up to our talk in comments: AWS Lambda must be expecting you to return a promise if the handler is an async function.

Try to promisify the `twitter.get()` function if you want to use an async handler:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log("The function started") // this line gets logged

  const twitter = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: process.env.consumer_key,
    consumer_secret: process.env.consumer_secret,
    access_token_key: process.env.access_token_key,
    access_token_secret: process.env.access_token_secret
  });

  const params = {
    screen_name: 'xxxx',
    count: 10,
    tweet_mode: 'extended'
  };
  const twitterEndpoint = 'statuses/user_timeline.json';

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    twitter.get(twitterEndpoint, params,  function(error, tweets, response) { //this doesn't...
      console.log("TWEETS", tweets, "ERROR", error, "RESPONSE", response) // this line does not log out
      if (!error) {
        console.log(tweets)
        resolve();
      }else{
        console.log(error, "There was an error calling twitter!")
        reject();
      }
    }); 
  });
}
```

Comment: Kind of weird that lambda cares what kind of response twitter gives. Also to clarify if you're using async anyway this method would also work.

`const tweets = await twitter.get(twitterEndpoint, params)`

Comment: It doesn't quite care what kind of response twitter gives, that is just how async/await behaves. If you were running normal Node and were trying to `await` the function in the original post, it wouldn't work either without the modifications I put in my answer.

Comment: And yes, if the twitter package returns promises when no callback is passed (which is becoming the standard), this should be your go-to.